# AWK command returning the data on a single column and concatenating data into a single line per result

Tags: awk

I have a csv file with some Vulnerability results from a scan performed in my environment...

I am trying to extract columns 4,5, 6,7 & 8 of the file in question.

I used:

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS="\r\n"; RS="\r\n"; FS=","; } { print $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 } scanresultsfile.csv > modified_file.csv
```

modified file returns the results in a single column with all fields of each column in a single line per result

example:

EXPECTED RESULTS:

```
Medium | "123.123.123.123" | tcp | JQuery 1.2 < 3.5.0 Multiple XSS |
Medium | "123.123.123.123" | tcp | JQuery 1.2 < 3.5.0 Multiple XSS |
Medium | "123.123.123.123" | tcp | JQuery 1.2 < 3.5.0 Multiple XSS |
```

ACTUAL RESULTS

```
Medium"123.123.123.123"tcp"443"JQuery 1.2 < 3.5.0 Multiple XSS
Medium"123.123.123.123"tcp"443"JQuery 1.2 < 3.5.0 Multiple XSS
Medium"123.123.123.123"tcp"443"JQuery 1.2 < 3.5.0 Multiple XSS
```

What could be causing this?... I have tried with and without adding comma in between the columns, with and without the `ORS` & `RS` flags. But do not get what I am expecting...  Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and look at some existing questions that have been upvoted and answered then [edit] your question to fix the formatting so it's legible and we can copy/paste your example to test with. Please also add the output of `awk --version` to your question and make sure to include the sample input in your [mcve] that you want to produce that expected output otherwise we have nothing to run a potential solution against.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use commas after each argument in the `print` statement. Awk uses blank as the concatenate operator. When you do that `OFS` regulates the field separator. So you will want `OFS=" | "`

Comment: So you are suggesting `awk 'BEGIN { ORS="\r\n"; RS="\r\n"; FS=",";  OFS=" | "} { print $4, $5, $6, $7, $8 } scanresultsfile.csv > modified_file.csv`?

Comment: Yes, that should work. If not, @htakeuchi could give a bit more info on the environment and awk version.